# Ubuntu 20.04 - LightDM Auto Login Not Consistently Working

Tags: 20.04, login, lightdm

I've got a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, but can't get auto login to work consistently.
The only workaround i've found is to add a 2 second wait time, but i want to get to the root of the issue.
Since it seems to work when i add a 2 second delay it makes me think that something else isn't loading fast enough.

Lightdm.conf without wait

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=TEST
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Lightdm.conf with wait

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=TEST
autologin-user-timeout=2
```

systemctl status lightdm.service output when it doesn't auto login.

```
    TEST@TEST_PC:~$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for TEST:
root@TEST_PC:~# systemctl status lightdm.service
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-03-24 12:13:48 AEDT; 22s ago
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
    Process: 3008 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SU>
   Main PID: 3012 (lightdm)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 2147)
     Memory: 62.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
             ├─3012 /usr/sbin/lightdm
             ├─3131 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
             └─3367 lightdm --session-child 12 19

Mar 24 12:13:48 TEST_PC systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Mar 24 12:13:48 TEST_PC systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Mar 24 12:13:49 TEST_PC lightdm[3032]: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user TEST by (uid=0)
Mar 24 12:13:52 TEST_PC lightdm[3140]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Mar 24 12:13:53 TEST_PC lightdm[3140]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Mar 24 12:13:55 TEST_PC lightdm[3367]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "TEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

> requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "TEST"

I think you should add user `TEST` into a group `nopasswdlogin`.

```sh
sudo addgroup TEST nopasswdlogin
```